# RecyclerView.Adapter notifyDataSetChanged() using ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-contentprovider, android-adapter

Hello I am using ContentProvider and after deleting elements by clicking a button my adapter does not notify, if i go back and come again the element is deleted. So ContentProvider works but notifyDataSetChanged(); doesn't.

```
public class CategoriesPreferedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesPreferedAdapter.ViewHolder> {


private List<ModelCategoriesProvider> feedItemList;
private Context mContext;

public CategoriesPreferedAdapter(Context context, List<ModelCategoriesProvider> feedItemList) {
    this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public CategoriesPreferedAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_prefered_adapter, parent, false);

    return new CategoriesPreferedAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView);

}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoriesPreferedAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    //holder.titleTextView.setText(mList[position]);
    final ModelCategoriesProvider feedItem = feedItemList.get(position);
    holder.setClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {

            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),""+feedItem.getId()+"  Users Delete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (isLongClick) {
            }


        }

    });



    holder.title.setText(feedItem.getName());

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(Links.ImagePath+feedItem.getImage())
            .centerCrop()
            // .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_porosiicon)
            .crossFade()
            .into(holder.categoryImage);

    System.out.println("image path "+feedItem.getImage());

    holder.delete_category.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //deleteId(feedItem.getId()+"");
            String[] whereArgs = {feedItem.getId()+""};
            int count  = mContext.getContentResolver().delete(UsersProvider.CONTENT_URI,UsersProvider.PID+" =?",whereArgs);
            // System.out.println("count erald mjeshtri + mbreti ndaj thuaj princ ndaj thuaj mbret: "+count);
            //EventBus.getDefault().post(new Db_Update("update"));
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{
    private TextView title,data,type,amount,billnr;
    private ImageView categoryImage,delete_category;
    private ItemClickListener clickListener;
    CardView card_view;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        card_view = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.repoName);
        categoryImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_category);
        delete_category = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewfavourites);
        itemView.setTag(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        clickListener.onClick(view, getPosition(), false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        clickListener.onClick(view, getPosition(), true);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide complete code. Maybe you are using a different list in adapter.

Comment: i provided complete code in adapter

Comment: Try updating your onClick method like this.

 `holder.delete_category.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //deleteId(feedItem.getId()+"");
            String[] whereArgs = {feedItem.getId()+""};
            int count  = mContext.getContentResolver().delete(UsersProvider.CONTENT_URI,UsersProvider.PID+" =?",whereArgs);
            feedItemList.remove(position)
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });`

Comment: Deleting from ContentProvider is fine, but you did not remove from the AdapterList, before notifyDataSetChange, delete from ArrayList like feedItemList.remove(position). Hope it helps

Comment: thank u @mvj, u solve my problem

Comment: thank u @RameshKumar that was the right answer

Comment: @EraldHaka, I have added this as Answer you can make Accept it as answer, because other can understand this logic. thanks

Comment: @RameshKumar done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting from `ContentProvider` is fine, but you did not remove from the `AdapterList`, before `notifyDataSetChange`, delete from `ArrayList` like

`feedItemList.remove(position);`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem like your problem and I solved this problem in this way:
In mine, I have an array "arrayBootable" that I fill recycled view with it.
You can use your ArrayList name and call this method when you want to notify your recycler

```
public static void notifyRecycler(){
  arrayBootable.clear();
  arrayBootable.addAll(bootable());
  favouriteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling notifyChange in the delete method of your content-provider. The way it works is, when the data attached to any view is updated, the notifyChange method notifies that view about the update. So, make sure, you have called  `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` inside the delete method in you CP.

The other reason may be, you are initialising the arraylist/list attached to the recyclerview adapter more than once. In that case, the link to the list is lost from the adapter and you have to `setAdapter` again. The recommended way is to call `clear` followed by `addAll` on the list.
like this:

```
list.clear();
list.addAll(your_new_data);
```

Let me know if it helps. 
Thanks!

Comment: yes the second answer id the main idea, i have forgot to declare feedItemList.remove(position); thank u for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try using notifyDataSetChanged() inside a runnable that posts data on UI thread through a handler.

Define your handler in a Utility method

```
private static Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

public static void postOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        mainHandler.post(runnable);
    }
```

Then in your code :

```
Utility.postOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // call notifyDataSetChanged here
            }
        });
```